# How to install or register a Saxon HE 10.3 Configuration? Configuration is not being used

Tags: java, xslt, internationalization, saxon, apache-fop

I'm trying to use a custom Configuration for saxon HE 10.3.

The Configuration is not being used. Presumably the config needs to be registered or installed? But how?
Here's my code:

```
final Configuration config = new net.sf.saxon.Configuration();
/**/                config.setLocalizerFactory(new LocalizerFactory() {
    public Numberer getNumberer(final String language, final String country) {
        if (language.equals("de")) {
            return  Numberer_de.getInstance();
        } else {
            return  null;
        }
    }
});
net.sf.saxon.Transform.main(new String[] {
        "-s:source.xml",
        "-xsl:stylesheet.xslt",
        "-o:result.txt"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was missing, was how to inject the Config. This worked for me:

```
import net.sf.saxon.Configuration;
import net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.Feature;

final TransformerFactoryImpl factory = (TransformerFactoryImpl) TransformerFactory.newInstance();
factory.getProcessor().setConfigurationProperty(Feature.CONFIGURATION, config);
```

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to be running `net.sf.saxon.Transform.main` from a Java application: use either the s9api or JAXP transformation APIs. The `net.sf.saxon.Transform.main` interface is designed for use from the command line, and it can therefore only modify the configuration through command line switches. It also has drawbacks like shutting down the Java VM if the transformation fails.

There is a workaround, which is to use the -init option on the command line to trigger user-supplied initialisation code (which has access to the Configuration object), but that's only really digging yourself deeper into your hole. I'd recommend switching to the s9api API.

Documentation: https://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xsl/embedding

Comment: I'm using Saxon HE as XSLT processor on the Classpath with apache FOP, but as dates weren't being formatted in german with xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(...) I'm just using this as a mockup to try & figure out how to get the internationalisation working. P.S: I tried plugging in ICU4J, but that had no effect either.

Comment: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory is returning a net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl, so its picking up Saxon ok & otherwise working fine, but I just can't figure out how I can get that LocalizerFactory registered.

Comment: Thanks for your invaluable input Michael & thanks for Saxon too :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the configuration when running Saxon from the command line, as Michael said, there is the `-init` option to pass in the name of a class implementing the `Initializer` interface https://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!javadoc/net.sf.saxon.lib/Initializer so you would use roughly e.g.

```
package com.example;


import net.sf.saxon.option.local.Numberer_de;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.Initializer;
import net.sf.saxon.Configuration;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.LocalizerFactory;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.Numberer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

public class MyInitializer implements Initializer {

public override void initialize(Configuration config) throws TransformerException {
  config.setLocalizerFactory(new LocalizerFactory() {
    public Numberer getNumberer(final String language, final String country) {
        if (language.equals("de")) {
            return  Numberer_de.getInstance();
        } else {
            return  null;
        }
    }
  });
}

}
```

compile that, put it on the classpath and then run e.g. `java -cp saxon-he-10.3.jar;com/example/MyInitializer;net/sf/saxon/option/local/Numberer_de net.sf.saxon.Transform -init:com.example.MyInitializer -s:source.xml -xsl:stylesheet.xslt -o:result.txt`.

Or you can subclass `net.sf.saxon.Transform`.

On the other hand, if you don't want to run Saxon from the command line but from the JAXP API then I think one approach is to create the `Configuration` e.g.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setLocalizerFactory(new LocalizerFactory() {
        public Numberer getNumberer(final String language, final String country) {
            if (language.equals("de")) {
                return  Numberer_de.getInstance();
            } else {
                return  null;
            }
        }
      });

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl(config);

Templates templates = transformerFactory.newTemplates(xsltSource);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Now to get back to the underlying problem: I'm calling something like TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTemplates(xsltSource).newTransformer().transform(xmlSource, foResult); How can I inject the Config into that environment?

Comment: So you are not running Saxon from the command line? In that case Michael Kay's answer and suggestion should help. If you need to use JAXP instead of s9api to easier interface with FOP then edit the question and add that information there.

Comment: @DaveTheDane, see whether the approach outlined in the edited answer works for you to use a custom configuration with JAXP.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It gave me the inspiration to find the solution.

Comment: Any idea how to get ICU4J working with Saxon HE? (I understand they are replacing the Localisation classes)

Comment: @DaveTheDane, not really, the publically documented API has https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/com/saxonica/config/pe/ICUNumbererPE.html and https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/com/saxonica/config/ICULibrary.html but what happens under the hood I don't know.